# Ambiguous Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite

I am try to build an issue Tracking system using springboot web, spring data JPA with SQlite database and Spring thymleaf. However, I keep running into the following errors when i try to run my application.

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.5.2)[0;39m

[2m2021-07-05 12:42:54.284[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.i.app.IssueTrackingApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting IssueTrackingApplication using Java 15.0.2 on User with PID 16980 (C:\Users\26097\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite projects\IssueTracking\target\classes started by 26097 in C:\Users\26097\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite projects\IssueTracking)
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:54.284[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.i.app.IssueTrackingApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:54.786[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:54.823[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.214[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.215[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.216[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.277[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.279[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 988 ms
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.382[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.395[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-2 - Starting...
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.404[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.407[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: com.issuetracking.app.SQLDialect
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.504[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.505[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.780[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'equipmentController' method 
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#addEquipment(Model)
to {GET [/equipment]}: There is already 'equipmentController' bean method
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#listEquipment(Model) mapped.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.781[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.782[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.785[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.786[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.800[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-07-05 12:42:55.853[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m16980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'equipmentController' method 
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#addEquipment(Model)
to {GET [/equipment]}: There is already 'equipmentController' bean method
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#listEquipment(Model) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.issuetracking.app.IssueTrackingApplication.main(IssueTrackingApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'equipmentController' method 
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#addEquipment(Model)
to {GET [/equipment]}: There is already 'equipmentController' bean method
com.issuetracking.app.controllers.EquipmentController#listEquipment(Model) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:663) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:629) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:328) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:395) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:298) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:224) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:206) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

And this is my controller that consists of the handler methods that handle the data that has been entered into the form, the one that lists the equipment details that are present in the database and the one that enables us to add the equipment details in the database using the form.

```
package com.issuetracking.app.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.issuetracking.app.enitities.Equipment;
import com.issuetracking.app.services.EquipmentService;

@Controller
public class EquipmentController {

    private EquipmentService equipmentService;

    public EquipmentController(EquipmentService equipmentService) {
        super();
        this.equipmentService = equipmentService;
    } 
    
    @GetMapping("/equipment")
    public String listEquipment(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("equipment",equipmentService.getAllEquipment()); 
        return "equipment";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/equipment")
    public String addEquipment(Model model) {
         Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
        model.addAttribute("equipment", equipment); 
        return "equipment"; 
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/equipment")
    public String saveEquipment(@ModelAttribute("equipment") Equipment equipment) {
    equipmentService.saveEquipment(equipment); 
    return "redirect:/equipment"; 
    }
    
}
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple methods with the same url. Change any one of them and it works.

GetMapping("/equipment") is mapped to 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping three times with the same URL please try another URL to map three of each method

```
 @GetMapping("/equipment")
    public String listEquipment(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("equipment",equipmentService.getAllEquipment()); 
        return "equipment";
    }
```

```
    @GetMapping("/equipment")
    public String addEquipment(Model model) {
         Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
        model.addAttribute("equipment", equipment); 
        return "equipment"; 
    }
```

```
 @PostMapping("/equipment")
    public String saveEquipment(@ModelAttribute("equipment") Equipment equipment) {
    equipmentService.saveEquipment(equipment); 
    return "redirect:/equipment"; 
    }
```

Comment: tried doing that and now when i try to submit the form is brings the following error: Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.issuetracking.app.enitities.Equipment'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'lights'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lights"]

Comment: @cool_Jay wherever in your form you are inserting "lights" makes sure the field of the data type is String in your entity class

Comment: it is a String  it is written like so @Column(name="Name_of_equipment")
 private String equipment;